# Unexpected result -- numpy fromfunction with constant functions

Tags: python, numpy

I was expecting `np.fromfunction(lambda i: 1, (4,), dtype=int)` to return `array([1, 1, 1, 1])`, but it returns the integer `1` instead. Can someone explain to me why numpy.fromfunction behaves that way? It seems to have something to do with the definition of the anonymous function (i.e., whether a parameter of the function is actually used).

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.fromfunction(lambda i: i, (4,), dtype=int)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])

>>> np.fromfunction(lambda i: 1, (4,), dtype=int)
1

>>> np.fromfunction(lambda i: 1 + i*0, (4,), dtype=int)
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

EDIT: to clarify, my ultimate goal isn't to create `array([1, 1, 1, 1])` using this method. Rather, I'm making a call of the form

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i: **an expression that doesn't depend on i**, (n,))
```

In other words, I'm trying to initialize a numpy array by repeatedly making a call to some function. (There's a call to np.random.random() in that function so I'm not making redundant calls.)

Comment: If the expression doesn't depend on `i`, I suspect you could replace the use of `a = np.fromfunction(lambda i: **an expression that doesn't depend on i**, (n,))` with something like `a = **an expression that doesn't depend on i**`, and in the expression, use something like `np.ones(n)`, `np.arange(n)`, etc., to have the expression create an array of the appropriate size.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I'm not sure I understand. Will your method work even if there's a call to `np.random.random()` inside `**an expression that doesn't depend on i**`?

Comment: You can use the `size` argument of `np.random.random`.  If your expression is, say, `4*u**2 + 1` where `u` is random, you can write `a = 4*np.random.random(size=n)**2 + 1`.

Answer (score 10):

@Warren Weckesser has explained why this is happening (the NumPy docs are a bit misleading here and nowhere make it clear that `fromfunction` is expecting a vector). If you want to make your `lambda` function work with `fromfunction` you can vectorize it explicitly:

```
In [1]: func = lambda i: 1
In [1]: vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
In [2]: np.fromfunction(vfunc, (4,), dtype=int)
Out[2]: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

But for this use case, I'd have thought

```
np.ones(4, dtype=int)
```

(perhaps times a constant) would be better.

Comment: Ah, that's useful to know. Thanks!

Comment: This issue will arise for any function that isn't natively vectorized, so the `np.vectorize` suggestion is more useful that the `np.ones` or `np.ones_like` suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

It is not explained well in the documentation of the `func` argument in the [`fromfunction`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) docstring that `func` is called just *once*, with array arguments.

In this example

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i: i, (4,), dtype=int)
```

the anonymous function is called once, with the argument `i` being the array [0, 1, 2, 3].   To verify this, you can do:

```
In [10] from __future__ import print_function

In [11]: np.fromfunction(lambda i: print("i = %r" % (i,)), (4,), dtype=int)
i = array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

In this case, where `func` returns 1,

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i: 1, (4,), dtype=int)
```

because the value returned by the single call is 1, the array that is created contains only 1.

It isn't clear why you would want to use `fromfunction` to create an array of 1s instead of, say, `np.ones`, but in case you have something more complicated in mind, here's one way you could do it, using `np.ones_like`:

```
In [14]: np.fromfunction(lambda i: np.ones_like(i), (4,), dtype=int)
Out[14]: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: This seems quite unintuitive. Is there a function that does what the OP intended to do?

Comment: Thanks -- that really clears up the behavior of fromfunction.

Comment: Here in 2023 this is still badly documented :-(  In fact, the docs state that fromfunction will "construct an array by executing a function over each coordinate" - with the use of *over each* strongly suggesting N function calls.